# Compling KUTE traffic generator 1.4 on Fedora Core 5

Tags: networking, fedora, compiling, kernel-modules

I am trying to install [KUTE](http://caia.swin.edu.au/genius/tools/kute/) traffic generator on Fedora Core 5 kernel version 2.6.15.

When I try to complile I get this error message:

```
[root@dhcppc128 kute-1.4]# make
make modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/kute-1.4'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.15-1.2054_FC5smp/build SUBDIRS=/kute-1.4 modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.15-1.2054_FC5smp/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: Entering an unknown directorymake: Leaving an unknown directorymake[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/kute-1.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Also I get errors when trying to patch.

I have been told I need to install the kernel headers, and I have tried installing the kernel headers and kernel devel from the DVD:

I have checked the kernel version and it is: `2.6.15-1.2054_FCSsmp i686`

I have tried the `kernel-smp-devel.2.6.15-1.2054_FC5.i686` RPM but it gives an error message.

```
rpm -i kernel-smp-devel-2.6.15-1.2054_FC5.i686.rpm
warning: kernel-smp-devel-2.6.15-1.2054_FC5.i686.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 4f2a6fd2
error: Failed dependencies:
/usr/sbin/hardlink is needed by kernel-smp-devel-2.6.15-1.2054_FC5.i686
```

Installing the `kernel-devel.2.6.15-1.2054_FC5.i686` RPM does work but I still get the same problem with compiling, even after a reboot.

I am guessing I need to install the SMP version?

P.S. I am running it on a P4 3.0 Ghz with 1 Gig RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora Core 5 is prehistoric, on its kernel you won't ever be able to build new modules. The in-kernel API is *far* from static.